# One of these words is not like the others, one of these words just isn't the same!

Tags: english, word-property, odd-one-out

Can you believe it?  I had a great list of words that all go together, and someone stuck in a word that doesn't belong. Can you take it out for me?

- addict
- affect
- conflict
- extract
- inject
- object
- perfect
- project
- reject
- subject
- suspect

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would say

> Inject
>  All others are also nouns
>  Inject is the only one that can only be a verb

Comment: Ninja'd by 19 secs...  But I'm wondering whether our answer is really what the OP had in mind...

Comment: Right answer, but I had a different reason in mind ... although it actually ties in with your explanation!  Upvote. :)

Comment: Is it stress related? All the nouns have stress on the first syllable, all the verbs on the last.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was thinking!! All the words but one can be pronounced 2 ways (verb sounds one way, noun sounds another way). Same answer, different reason. I'll accept this as The Answer!

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps:

> inject

Because the others are all:

> both nouns* and verbs, whereas "inject" is only a verb
>
>  * I thought "perfect" and "affect" weren't nouns either but the dictionary says they are

Comment: You might just say "all the others are ambiguous between nouns and verbs, or nouns and adjectives (in the case of *perfect*). *Inject* is NOT ambiguous; it's always a verb.

Comment: By the way, you ninja'd me. +1

Comment: @Silenus: Levieux ninja'd both of us.   :)

Comment: Concur. Inject does not stand as a noun in English. The others can.

Comment: Upvote, and the same comment I left for @Levieux.

Comment: @Silenus You can perfect something; it's a verb too. "to perfect".

Answer (score 3):

Another possible answer would be

> suspect

as it is the only word that cannot

> be made into a new word by 'ion' to the end.

Comment: Verrrrrry interesting! But I don't think "conflict" fits that rule either.

Comment: @CreatedByBrett I think your objection is in confliction with the inflection in this definition:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confliction
;)

Comment: Wooooow! I had no idea "confliction" was a verb! (Even my browser says it's spelled wrong! lol)

Answer (score -1):

I had suggested

> "perfect" as the only adjective, but "subject" can also be an adjective, as in "He was subject to fits of hysteria".